# UWP Unit Test App starts but no tests run

Tags: unit-testing, uwp

I can't get UWP unit tests to run for our project.  The app starts, then closes, and in the Test output there is an error:

> [4/11/2018 7:36:42 Informational] ------ Run test started ------
>
> [4/11/2018 7:37:05 Error] **An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://mstestadapter/v2': Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: key**
>
> [4/11/2018 7:37:09 Informational] ========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:26.8121266) ==========

I tried deleting the .vs folder, all the bin and obj folders, and restarting Visual Studio.

Comment: Do you try to deploy the uwp unit test project? After deploy maybe it could run?